# Which part of a cap is called the bill?

Tags: meaning

I came across this line

> There was only the New York Yankees baseball cap lying there, mold
>   crusted on its bill.

I was wondering what part of the cap is called its bill.

Comment: The part that looks like [the bill (beak) of a duck](http://www.chinawholesaletown.com/wholesale-Duck-Baseball-Cap_8633097774d464b0a808f18web_up_file.jpg). Technically only  *bill caps* have bills, and there are other kinds of caps which don't have bills, but in contemporary American culture, the bill cap is the dominant form of hat, so the name can be (and generally is) shortened to *cap*, without creating any real ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. If you post this as an answer I could pick it as the right one. Also I didn't what tags should I put to this question. Could you suggest some?

Comment: Vivek: 'bill cap' is a technical term (of which I have never heard, but understand what is meant under this discussion). It's almost always referred to as 'baseball cap' or 'hat' (hardly ever 'cap' by itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is a picture of a typical baseball cap with the parts labeled. The bill protrudes outward (to shade the eyes from sunlight and to keep rain off the face) and somewhat resembles a duck's bill, as @DanBron said in the comments.

[image: http://epicsports.cachefly.net/products/BuyersGuide/BaseballCapDiagram.jpg]

"Baseball" caps are not confined to baseball. For example, below is a baseball-style cap (with bill) made with the Buffalo Bills (an American football team) logo. Of course the Bills hat would be worn by a fan, not by an active player on the field, whereas baseball caps are worn on the field by most of the defensive players.

[image]

Comment: Baseball caps aren't even limited to sports anymore. You can find them with pretty much anything on them, from corporate logos (Coca-Cola, FedEx, etc.) to the names of national parks and tourist destinations. You can even find them with nothing on them at all except sequins or some pattern.

Comment: They are so widely used for advertising that they are sometimes called "gimme" caps.

Comment: I've also heard "snap-backs" and "strap-backs" to distinguish the one-size-fits-all type from fitted caps.

Comment: I see what you did there!  Bill caps; Buffalo Bills...why not show Bill Clinton wearing one?